# What isn't the metric invariant under translation with killing vectors?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry, vector-fields, invariants

I am learning about Killing Vectors in GR class, and I'm testing my knowledge of them as a start with the Minkowski metric.

I used the simple 2d Minkowski metric:

$$ds^2 = -dt^2 + dx^2$$

and got 3 killing vectors:

$$\xi_{(1)} = \left[ \begin{array}{} 1 \\ 0 \end{array} \right] \ , \xi_{(2)} = \left[ \begin{array}{} 0 \\ 1 \end{array} \right] \ , \xi_{(3)} = \left[ \begin{array}{} t \\ x \end{array} \right]$$

Which makes sense because these are the generators of translations and boosts.
Knowing that if I define $v' = v + \epsilon\xi_{(3)}$, then:

$g_{\mu \nu}(v') = g'_{\mu \nu}(v')=g_{\sigma \rho}(v)\frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial x'^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x' ^ \nu}$

As per the definition of Killing Vectors, however, $g_{\mu \nu}$ is constant, so $g_{\mu \nu}(v') = g_{\mu \nu}(v) \neq g_{\sigma \rho}(v)\frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial x'^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x' ^ \nu} = \frac{1}{1+\epsilon}g_{\mu \nu}(v) \approx (1-\epsilon)g_{\nu\mu}(v)$.

So what am I doing wrong in here?

Comment: The issue is with your definition of Killing vectors. It’s the metric tensor that is conserved, not its individual components.